# Pytest setup_method executes before xdist worker_id fixture

Tags: python, pytest, xdist

Pytest `setup_method` executes before `xdist` `worker_id` fixture
is it possible to get worker id before start of `setup_method`?

e.g. I have:

Content of `conftest.py`:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def worker_id(request):
    print("worker")
    if hasattr(request.config, 'slaveinput'):
        request.config.worker = request.config.slaveinput['slaveid']
    else:
        request.config.worker = "master"
    return request.config.worker
```

Content of `test.py`:

```
class TestSomething:

    def setup_method(self):
        print("setup")

    def test_something(self):
        print("test")
```

And the output is:

```
setup
worker
test
```

Comment: This is the known [bug](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/517) for pytest. You can use fixture in place of setup method.

Answer (score 0):

How you are getting worker_id ?

suppose we launched 4 process using pytest -n 4
now four process were launched named pw[0], pw[1], pw[2] & pw[3].

I would allocate user1 credentials to process1 and user2 credentials to process2 based on name that pw[0] & pw[1]

Is it possible to implement

Comment: Yes

def pytest_configure(config):
    if hasattr(config, 'slaveinput'):
        config.worker = config.slaveinput['slaveid']
        allocate_user(config.worker)
    else:
     config.worker = 'master'

http://take.ms/ARMN2